# Cannot convert timestamp to date in Python with correct timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame as the following:

```
timestamp
1583985600000
1584072000000
1584331200000
1584417600000
1584504000000
1584590400000
```

There are actually other columns as well but I pasted the above one for the sake of simplicity.

I need to change this column to date format by creating a separate column within the same DataFrame. I try the following:

```
df["date EST"] = pd.to_datetime(agg_daily_df["timestamp"],
                    unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('EST').astype(str)
```

... which gives the following result:

```
date EST
2020-03-12 04:00:00-05:00
2020-03-13 04:00:00-05:00
2020-03-16 04:00:00-05:00
2020-03-17 04:00:00-05:00
2020-03-18 04:00:00-05:00
2020-03-19 04:00:00-05:00
```

... which looks quite strange to me. The first row should actually give
`2020-03-12 00:00:00`.

What is it I am doing wrong here so that I get results in a strange format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return time in UTC as tz-naive datetime.

```
pd.to_datetime(agg_daily_df["timestamp"], unit='ms')

# 1583985600000 => 2020-03-12 04:00:00
```

So, localizing this datetime, it results in

```
original:       1583985600000 => 
pd.to_datetime: 2020-03-12 04:00:00 (tz-naive) => 
tz_localize:    2020-03-12 04:00:00-05:00 (tz-aware, EST)
```

The issue is that you need to have tz-aware datetime before converting to other timezone.

```
# Add utc=True to get tz-aware time and convert to EST
(pd.to_datetime(agg_daily_df["timestamp"], unit='ms', utc=True)
   dt.tz_convert('EST'))
```

This way the time will be converted like this.

```
original:                  1583985600000 => 
to_datetime with utc=True: 2020-03-12 04:00:00+00:00 (tz-aware, UTC) => 
tz_convert:                2020-03-11 23:00:00-05:00 (tz-aware, EST)
```

Note that "EST" timezone doesn't handle day light saving. If you would like to have the day light saving handling, use locale for timezone.

```
(pd.to_datetime(agg_daily_df["timestamp"], unit='ms', utc=True)
   .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York'))
```

This will give you `2020-03-12 00:00:00-04:00`.

========================================================

Update:

If you would like to have tz-naive time again, remove tzinfo by `tz_localize(None)`

```
 (pd.to_datetime(agg_daily_df["timestamp"], unit='ms', utc=True)
   .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
   .tz_localize(None))
```

Or if you are just want to have time without showing timezone offset, use `strftime` to format datetime into string.

```
(pd.to_datetime(agg_daily_df["timestamp"], unit='ms', utc=True)
   .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
   .transform(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanation! But the format of the result should be 2020-03-12 00:00:00 instead of 2020-03-12 00:00:00-04:00. How do I achieve this? Additionally, day light saving is important as well. I would like to convert the timestamp to the local time in EST. How do I achieve that by taking day light saving into consideration as well?

Comment: Do you want to have tz-naive datetime object or just a format without timezone offset?  
For handling of day light saving, I already noted in the answer (last section from "Note that...").

Comment: Now everything is clearer. Thank you very much for taking the time to give such a detailed explanation.